# Is it possible to create the new iOS 17 iMessage Animation in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-animation

I have a perfect use-case for this animation inside my Application, but I don't really have experience with the Flutter Animation Framework. Additionally the Resources Online regarding this Animation are very scarce, so I would appreciate it if someone could lead me to some kind of Solution!

Here is the Animation for Reference: https://imgur.com/a/sHCDuZw

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.